# Calculations for current transformer and output voltage

Tags: current-transformer

I'm trying to understand differences in my simulation (LTSpice) of a current transformer from calculations of the output voltage and current. In LTSpice with a 600ohm resistor across the secondaries; I get 18V and 30mA pk-pk. Obviously Im not taking into account all the factors and losses? How do I calculate the value of the resistor on the output for a given voltage? R = Vs/Is?

Current Transformer Spec

Source:

```
Current    = 10A pk-pk.
Freq       = 50Hz
```

Primary:

```
Turns      = 10
Inductance = 200uH
Resistance = 0.2 ohms
```

Secondary:

```
Turns      = 300
Inductance = 180mH
Resistance = 12 ohms
```

Verify Turns to Inductance:

```
Np / Ns = SQRT(Lp/Ls) 
0.0333  = 0.0333
```

Calculate Voltage and Current:

```
Np/Ns = Vp/Vs = Is/Ip

Vp = Ip * Rp 
Vp = 10 * 0.2 = 2Vpk-pk   <-- Verified as 2V pk pk in LTSpice.
```

Calculations:

```
Is = Ip * (Np / Ns) 
Is = 10 * (10 / 300) = 333mA   <-- 30mA pk-pk in LTSpice
Vs = Vp / (Np / Ns) = 2 / (10 / 300) = 60V <-- 18V pk-pk in LTSpice
```

(unfortunately I cant added LTSpice pics due to an error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\boxed{\text{Right up front - your burden resistor is far too high for this design}}$$

The whole point about CTs is that the primary magnetization inductive reactance is overwhelmed by the reflected burden resistance. Your turns ratio is 1:30 because that equals: -

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{\text{180 mH}}{\text{200 μH}}}$$

And the 600 Ω load reflects to the primary as a resistance of: -

$$\text{600 Ω}\cdot\dfrac{1}{900} = 0.667 \text{ Ω}$$

But, at 50 Hz the primary reactance is: -

$$2\pi\cdot 50\cdot 200\text{ μH} = 0.0628\text{ Ω}$$

And that impedance is certainly not overwhelmed by the reflected secondary impedance of 0.667 Ω. In other words, your burden resistor on the secondary needs to be a whole lot lower than 600 Ω. A whole lot lower if you want accuracy.

> *How do I calculate the value of the resistor on the output for a given
> voltage?*

You don't because you are constrained by other things.

So, you determine the primary magnetization inductive reactance (0.0628 Ω for 200 μH at 50 Hz) and you say to yourself: -

$$\boxed{\text{I need to make my burden reflected impedance much lower}}$$

So, if you went for something like 100 times lower i.e. 0.0006 Ω you would find that when transferred to the secondary, it is a resistance of: -

$$\text{0.0006 Ω}\times 900 = 0.54 Ω$$

That would be a good value for a burden resistor.

---

Secondary resistance as stated by the OP: -

```
Resistance = 12 ohms
```

This is too much for your design. Can you see that based on the above calculations? It's the same story with your primary resistance of 0.2 Ω. You just cannot expect a CT to operate anything like a CT is meant to operate with these resistance values. Just think about it; you say the primary current is 10 amps and that means your primary winding is dissipating 20 watts of \$I^2R\$ power losses. Be realistic.

Comment: unfortunately that's also in series with the secondary resistance of 12 ohms as far as loading the primary inductance is concerned, so it's a really naff current transformer, it would struggle for a factor of 10, let alone the 100 you're using. I like the boxed markup BTW.

Comment: `$$\boxed{\text{Neil is cool}}$$` $$\boxed{\text{No he's not}}$$

Comment: @Neil - the secondary resistance is a whopping big factor. He needs to wind it from something with much lower resistance.

Comment: Rereading the question, he may not have a physical transformer, just an LTSpice model with some inductances which are in the right ratio to get the turns ratio, but don't represent a realistic transformer.

Comment: Yes & small Transformers are usually designed for 10% loss at full load, big ones 1%.